# Regex expression inquiry matching position

Tags: regex, python-3.x, match, findall

I'm trying to match a string with the regex expression below. At the 11th term, I would like the 11th character to be the same as of the 1st character and the 12th character be the same as of the 2nd character on Python 3. I've tried \1\2 as instructed on hackerrank, but it is giving an error while running the code.

```
  strcom = 'ab #1?AZa$ab #1?AZa$'
  match = re.findall(r'[a-z]\w\s\W\d\D[A-Z][a-zA-Z][aeiouAEIOU]\S\1\2',strcom)
```

Comment: you have to use parenthesis to capture: `re.findall(r'([a-z])(\w)\s\W\d\D[A-Z][a-zA-Z][aeiouAEIOU]\S\1\2',strcom)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) as [Onyambu suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52601583/regex-expression-inquiry-matching-position/52604036#comment92137801_52601583), but to get the match you should use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) (if you expect multiple matches) or [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) to find a single match (or [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) if you only expect a single match at the start of the string).

```
import re
strcom = 'ab #1?AZa$ab #1?AZa$'
for m in re.finditer(r'([a-z])(\w)\s\W\d\D[A-Z][a-zA-Z][aeiouAEIOU]\S\1\2', strcom):
    print(m.group())

# => ab #1?AZa$ab
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/gtpkX9)

The problem with [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) is that it will only return captured substrings if capturing groups are defined in the pattern.